# Splitting a Select Input for on page Dynamic Form Creation as well as sending value to Form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I need to split a select input in two parts in order to use one part for dynamic form creation on the same page and the second part to be sent to the receiving form.

This is what I have now to dynamically create the div below based on the select input selection:

```
$a = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $people_array[$a] = array(
    "ID"          => $row['ID'],
    "event"       => $row['name'],
    "time_needed" => $row['time_needed'],
  );
$a = $a + 1; 
}
$count = count($people_array);

<form>
<?php for($p=0,$p<$count,p++){
  $segment_id = $people_array[$p][ID]; ?>
  <select name="name_segment" id="name_segment">
    <option value="female" >
      <?php echo $people_array[$p][name]; ?>
    </option>
    <option value="male" >
      <?php echo $people_array[$p][name]; ?>
    </option>
  </select>
<?php } ?>
</form>

<div id="name_segment_female" class="name_segment_input" style="display:none;">
  Allow at least 30 extra minutes for bathroom usage.
</div>
<div id="name_segment_male" class="name_segment_input" style="display:none;">
  No extra bathroom time needed.
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
<script>
$("#name_segment").change(function() {
  var name_segment = $(this).val();
  $(".name_segment_input").hide();
  $("#name_segment_" + name_segment).show("slow");
});
</script>
```

Searching here on stackoverflow, I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-select-tag-carry-multiple-values) that got me started with this: `<option value="{type:'amount',segment_id:'<?php echo $segment_id; ?>'} >`.  I just need to know how I can split this object up with javascript before submitting the page.  I need to have the hidden div display dynamically using the same value from the option input as a more specific value that will be sent to the receiving page for the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I changed options values all to be the same length for simplicity.
for example I left "male" the same but changed female to "fmle"
Then I changed the javascript:

```
$("#name_segment").change(function() {
  var name_segment = $(this).val();
  var local_segment = name_segment.slice(0,4);
  $(".name_segment_input").hide();
  $("#name_segment_" + local_segment).show("slow");
});
```

to parse out just the four letter section and use similarly as the original design.  Then I changed the options values to `<option value="fmle_<?php echo $segment_id; ?>" >`.  The `segment_id` will be parsed out server side after the submission of the form.

If completely necessary we can do a little more work to only send the `segment_id` as the original question asked but this will achieve the desired objective.