# issiues with the value of the multidropdown php

Tags: php, arrays, forms

This is my multidropdown

```
<select style="width:250px"name="locatie[]"id="contact" data-    
    placeholder="contactpersoon" class="chosen-select" id="e9"multiple tabindex="4"> 
        <option value=""></option> 
        <option value="United States, aaa, bbb, ccc">United States</option> 
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
</select>
```

this is my php code

```
$arr = $_POST["contact"];
reset($arr);
while (list(, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

When i select all the options,

OUTPUT

> Value: United States, aaa, bbb, ccc
>
> Value: United Kingdom
>
> Value: Afghanistan

how can i seperate the first value (united states, aaa, bbb, ccc) TO

> Value: United States
>
> Value: aaa
>
> Value: bbb
>
> Value: ccc
>
> Value: United Kingdom
>
> Value: Afghanistan

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place, why is there such a value in the list? It looks malformed, no?

Comment: i want to insert in mysql with a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the array first, split the string and add all the values to a new array:

```
<?php

$original = $_POST['contact'];
$output = array();

reset($original);

foreach($original as $value) {
    if(strpos($value, ',') === false)
        $output[] = $value; // add value straight away if it doesn't need splitting
    else {
        // split string by comma and trim whitespace from pieces
        $bits = explode(',', $value);
        foreach($bits as $bit) {
            $output[] = trim($bit);
        }
    }
}

// now loop through $output array to get desired result:
foreach($output as $value) {
    echo "Value: " . $value . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: beat me to the punch ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [Can an Option in a Select tag carry multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-select-tag-carry-multiple-values)

You could try using a JSON array instead of a comma-delimited list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure that I follow what you want and need,, BUT to separate the first value into individual items and list them in the order in which you demonstrate your list you should split and trim the string that represents your first value... while in the while loop...

To split the string with a string you can look at function explode in PHP

```
http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
```

To trim, look at this

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
```

Your string "United States, aaa, bbb, ccc" has to be split by a comma character ","  and then elements of the split array have to be trimmed to get rid of the white space that precedes them. As far as the code goes I will give you sort of a pseudo code that you can adjust for your needs.

```
  $arr = $_POST["contact"];
  reset($arr);

  while (list(, $value) = each($arr)) {

      // when you split the string you get an array and if the number of elements in an array is more then 1 that means your string contains a comma.. You split a string into subvalues and echo them in a loop...

      if (count(explode(",", $value)) > 1) { 

          $subvalues = explode(",", $value);
          foreach ($subvalue in $subvalues){ 
          echo "Value: trim($subvalue)<br />\n"; 
          }    
      } else {
          echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
      }

  }
```