# Two values in one checkbox with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, checkbox

Can I have two values in checkbox. Normally if I assign single value to checkbox, whenever I check or uncheck this checkbox it return me value, but I want this behavior only if I check the value(eventually alternative behavior).
I tried this way, but it didn't work

```
<input type="checkbox" name="path" id="path" defaultChecked={true} 
       value={ this.checked ?userData.image : ''} onChange={onChangeText}/>
```

Ofcourse I can do it in onChange function, but I want to find more simple and 'aesthetic' way, without

`getElementById or e.target.name== ? something() : somethingElse()`

And I want to do it in React.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264619/html-submit-multiple-values-through-one-check-box/29265261 You may get some clues from here

Comment: I did that before and probably will stay with it, because that looks that I can't do it this way and this trick with hidden checkbox doesn't work in React.

Comment: Please add more detail so we can understand what you are trying to do. Specifically, make a more complete example. The first example is incomplete because `this.checked` is undefined. (You probably should be using `this.state.checked` instead anyway.) Your second code snippet has syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you're saying you want a more simple and 'aesthetic' way, you are actually thinking to difficult. I would stick with an onchange function as it improves readability in your code, which also is easier to track down when coming back at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You. can simply move the turnery operator for value to onChange method as follow.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="path" id="path" defaultChecked={true} 
       onChange={(event) => onChangeText(event.target.checked ? userData.image : '')}/>
```