# Object Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an empty drop down list in HTML. I am trying to add new attribute into the list using .createElement('option') method. However, the item i want to add has name, address, and phone number so how can i add,as an object, into drop down list? Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Have you considered adding a string representation of the object (e.g. `Joe Egan (San Diego, CA) @ 858-876-5309`)?

Comment: So this is what have for now

Comment: <select id = "droplist">

</select>



function additem(name, address, phone){
 var opt = document.createElement("option");
 var sel = document.createElement("droplist");
 //now i have three attributes name, address and phone, and i want to make an object which will consist of these three attributes
 sel.add(opt,"i want to add object but only show its name in the list");
 }

Comment: Could found your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values). Display only a text with multiple value option.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you wanted, I got it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add

```
var sel = document.getElementById("existingList");

var opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.value = "3";
opt.text = "Option: Value 3";

sel.add(opt, sel.options[1]);
```

**[Edit]**

Im pretty tierd and the code is not the best. Maybe you can play around with it and see if it fits your code.

```
var sel = document.createElement("droplist"); 
var opt1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
var opt2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
var opt3 = document.createElement("OPTION");

var information = {
  names: ["nameOne", "nameTwo"],
  addresses: ["adressOne", "adressTwo"],
  names: ["phoneOne", "phoneTwo"],
  informationFunction: function additem(){ 
    opt1.value = "1";
    opt1.text = this.addresses[0];    
    opt2.value = "2";
    opt2.text = this.addresses[1];    
    opt3.value = "3";
    opt3.text = this.addresses[3];
    sel.appendChild(opt1);
    sel.appendChild(opt2);
    sel.appendChild(opt3);
  } 
};
information.informationFunction();
```

Comment: <select id = "droplist">

</select>



function additem(name, address, phone){
 var opt = document.createElement("option");
 var sel = document.createElement("droplist");
 /**now i have three attributes name, address and phone, and i want to make an object which will consist of these three attributes**/
 sel.add(opt,"i want to add object but only show its name in the list");
 }