# How to select the multiple value or search and set the value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the small code which was trying. In this we have multiple value for all the select options. I get this idea from this [Can an Option in a Select tag carry multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values) . Please help me out with this i'm new to jquery.

```
<select id="gate">
<option value='null'>- choose -</option>
<option value='Gateway 1,Gateway 3'>Gateway 1</option>
<option value='Gateway 2,Gateway 4'>Gateway 2</option>
</select>

$("#gate").val('Gateway 3');
```

The result got is empty in the drop down.

Comment: You can assign multiple value like this but HTML will assume that as a single value. So you can do something like this and it will work: `$("#gate").val('Gateway 1,Gateway 3');`

Comment: I can give only one value and it has to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this.

```
$("#gate").val( $("#gate option[value*='Gateway 3']").attr("value") )
```

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/zLh92h6b/1/

With variable

```
var str = "Gateway 3";
$("#gate").val( $("#gate option[value*='" + str + "']").attr("value") );
```

Comment: awesome answer it helped a lot. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ebilgin one more help.. what if we replace "Gateway 3" with a variable. i'm getting error in replacing with variable

Comment: @user2470026 I updated my answer with variable version.