# Multiple values from f.select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-helpers

This shouldn't be a problem but I can't figure it out.

Using form helpers I populate a select field like so:

```
...
  <%= f.select(:entity_id, entities.map {|entity| [entity.name, entity.id]}) %>
...
```

This is to create a `User` and set their `entity_id`. After the form submission I now have a new `User` whose `entity_id` is now the value of the option from the select field.

For example if I had selected "Store A" as my entity from the select element, the `entity_id` for that user is now '1' after I submit the form. This is great but I also need the `entity_name` "Store A" associated with the user.

So instead of my new user returning the following:

```
#<User name: 'John Doe', entity_id: '1', entity_name: 'Store A'>
```

I am getting

```
#<User name: 'John Doe', entity_id: '1', entity_name: nil>
```

Which makes sense becuase I never set `entity_name`.

How would I set `entity_name` in this form based on the selection ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks like you want to set two values at the same time for a single input box. Rails does not provide a simple way to do this but it seems that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245995/5129208) is similar to what you want.

However, I'd still ask the question: Why try to do it all on form submission?

You are already setting the `entity_id` on the `User` so you have a few options.

1. Assuming that `entities` is a relation of ActiveRecord or some other ORM  objects, you could let the association do the work. If a user `has_one :entity`  and then needs to know its `entity_name` then it could look like: `user.entity.name` after you set the correct `entity_id` on said `user`. This leverages the built in relationship framework Rails provides and keeps you from duplicating data.
2. If `entities` is not a relation or set of persisted objects, the code you used to generate the form must have known about `entities` during render time so it stands to reason that you would have access to it again. In the controller that accepts this form, fetch `entities` the same way you have done previously and link the entity with the submitted `entity_id`'s name to the `User` you are updating.
3. If neither of these are feasible or make sense, go ahead and use the JSON encoded form values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.select :entity_id,
            options_from_collection_for_select(@entities, :id, :name, entities),
            {},
            {
              data: { placeholder: "Choose entity..." },
              multiple: true
            } %>
```