# I want every option accept two or more value with php in HTML

Tags: php, html

here is the code

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Privilege Type:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <select style="width: 210px;" name="data[CreditCard][privilege_type][]" multiple='true'>
                            <option value="">Select Privilege Type</option>
                            <option value="Air miles">Air miles</option>
                            <option value="Cashback">Cashback</option>
                            <option value="Airport lounges">Airport lounges</option>
                             <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
                              <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
                        </select> 
                        <p>Press Ctrl to select more than one privilege type</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

for example i want option 3 accept Air miles also Airport lounges together in the same option

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">

                            <option value=""><?php echo  __('All Priviliges'); ?></option>
                            <option value="Air miles"><?php echo  __('Air Miles'); ?></option>
                            <option value="Airport lounges"><?php echo  __('Airport Lounges'); ?></option> 
                            <option value="Dining"><?php echo  __('Dining'); ?></option>
                            <option value="Shopping"><?php echo  __('Shopping'); ?></option>
                            <option value="cashback"><?php echo  __('CashBack'); ?></option>
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using check boxes, my friend.

Selects are made to receive only one input.

I did find this post, however, using a simple google search.....

[Can an Option in a Select tag carry multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values)

Comment: as stated before, you should consider using checkboxes.  that is my answer.