# How to convert string to object in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object, converters

I have a string like :

```
$scope.text = '"{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"age\":454 }"';
```

and I want to convert to js object:

```
 $scope.tmp =  {"firstName":"John","age":454 };
```

> Note: `JSON.parse()` doesn't work!!
>
> It's my sample in [codepen](http://codepen.io/essvision/pen/PzjGpQ)

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is what I think you're looking for. - Also, this is a duplicate.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. OP asks for the best answer within its framework (angular). I know JSON.Parse() works, but there is something else to do it with angular, for some reasons.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, `JSON.parse()` doesn't work

Comment: This is due to the extra quotes. Take off the outer single quotes, and then `JSON.parse` will work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it with [angular.fromJson()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)

in your sample, it would have been `$scope.tmp = angular.fromJson($scope.text);`

The difference between `JSON.Parse()` and `angular.fromJson`, is that angular will check to make sure a string is provided. If it is already an object, it will return the same object.

Comment: please check your answer in my [http://codepen.io/essvision/pen/PzjGpQ]

Comment: You have to remove your simple quotes around your string to make it work : `$scope.text = "{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"age\":454 }";`

Comment: Worked like magic!