# Pass Multiple Values In HTML Option Tag Via PHP

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a site with multiple sections, each with multiple categories, and need to pass 2 values through the form to add articles to my table. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do with my `Form` + `PHP` file:

```
<select name="sec-cat">
<option value-1="0">Select One</option>
<option value-1="0">---</option>
<option value-1="music" value-2="news">News Updates</option>
<option value-1="music" value-2="features">Features</option>
<option value-1="music" value-2="articles">Articles</option>
<option value-1="0" value-2="0">---</option>
<option value-1="lifestyle" value-2="news">News Updates</option>
<option value-1="lifestyle" value-2="features">Features</option>
<option value-1="lifestyle" value-2="articles">Articles</option>
etc
```

*I know that `value-1` & `value-2` aren't valid, but hopefully it will give an idea of wht I'm trying to do*

```
<?php
$section = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sec-cat']); // Value-1
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sec-cat']); // Value-2

if($section === '0'){
echo "No Section Specified";
exit();
}
?>
```

Is there a solution for extracting values 1 & 2 using a simple PHP method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an Option in a Select tag carry multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values)

Comment: Saw this for the JSON solution but missed the php answer beneath. I'll give the `explode` method a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see one way of doing it:
Add extra data to your post, separated by a known delimiter.
So, your input field would change from this:

```
<option value-1="music" value-2="news">News Updates</option>
```

Into this:

```
<select name="sec-cat">
<option value="music_news" >News Updates</option>
```

And on the server you can get the values like this:

```
$catRetVal = explode ('_',$POST['sec-cat']);
echo $catRetVal[0];
echo $catRetVal[1];
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: It is as same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/16229998/2679536. and this is a better solution than others.

Comment: Yes - possible duplicate.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll give this a try now and see what the results are. Thanks Pedro!

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer - it would be my first.

Comment: I edited the code to `$seccat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sec-cat']);
$seccat_explode = explode ('_',$seccat);
$section =  $seccat_explode[0];
$category =  $seccat_explode[1];`, for use when adding to a table - But this works perfectly. Thanks again.