# Send multiple values from dropdown view to the controller action

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown box where the data is coming from my database. I want to send the selected drop-down item to the controller action method. And then I will send these values to the model to do the further works. Here, the problem is I have two database values in a single item of drop-down box. And, I am not figuring out how to send those two the method. Here is my code given below,

```
<select name='select'>
        <option selected disabled>Choose Stations</option>
        <?php foreach ($get_stations as $get_stations_item): ?>
            <option>Station <?php echo $get_stations_item['sourcestationid']; ?> - Station <?php echo $get_stations_item['destinationstationid']; ?></option> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

From this dropdown items, I want to send the sourcestationid and destinationstationid separately as 2 parameters to my controller action method. Here is my controller code though this is not correct way I think,

```
function getdata(){
    $iotdata['test'] = $this->input->post('select2');
    //rest of the code according to the source and destination id item
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to send which variable sourcestationid or destinationstationid ?

Comment: I need to send both station id. @BitsPlease

Comment: Store your source and destination id in data attribute of option as

 <option data-sourceid="yoursource id" data-destinationeid="yourdestination id">one</option>

 tha on change of your select pass both data-sourceid and data-destinationeid to your controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't kept the variable inside option's value tag.

```
     <select name='select'>
    <option selected disabled>Choose Stations</option>
    <?php foreach ($get_stations as $get_stations_item): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $get_stations_item['sourcestationid'].','.$get_stations_item['destinationstationid']; ?>">Station <?php echo $get_stations_item['sourcestationid']; ?> - Station <?php echo $get_stations_item['destinationstationid']; ?></option> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Also here at PHP end, you can explode the string into an array and store it further into db.

```
<?php
$select = explode(',', $select)
print_r($select); // this will have your two values
?>
```

Comment: I need to send both station id to the controller action. Because for the same source station, I have different destination stations and vice-versa. @Bits Please

Comment: In my controller, this is giving this error. Undefined variable: select @Bits Please

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @BitsPlease for our suggestion. Your idea is working. But I need to do a small change to get it instantly. My select tag needs to be under form tag to get them without reloading the page again. Here is my view,

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo site_url("controller/action"); ?>">
        <select name='select' onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option selected disabled>Choose Stations</option>
            <?php foreach ($get_stations as $get_stations_item): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $get_stations_item['sourcestationid'].','.$get_stations_item['destinationstationidr']; ?>">Station <?php echo $get_stations_item['sourcestationid']; ?> - Station <?php echo $get_stations_item['destinationstationidr']; ?></option> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Here is the php code,

```
$select = explode(',', $this->input->post('select'));
print_r($select)
```