# How to search for a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a div based on a drop down selection. With some drop downs, I have multiple "values" and this is where I have the problem. How can I have the javascript only see the string in the "VALUE" until the comma.

This code works if I change

value = 'ABCD,asdf;

to

value = 'ABCD'

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').on('change', function() {

  if ( this.value == 'ABCD')
  {
    $("#rrrr").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#rrrr").hide();
  }


   });
 })
 </script>

    <select id='test' name = 'test'>
    <option value = '123'>hide div</option>
    <option value = 'ABCD,asdf'>display div</option>
      </select>
      <input type='submit' name = 'submit' value='Apply'>

     <div style='display:none;' id='rrrr'>

     display this section
           </div>
```

Ho can I use value = 'ABCD,asdf' so that I can show the div when teh value contains the string until the comma? I need to have 2 strings in the value

Comment: You can use the [includes() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the [includes() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value.includes('ABCD')) {
      $("#rrrr").show();
    } else {
      $("#rrrr").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test' name = 'test'>
  <option value = '123'>hide div</option>
  <option value = 'ABCD,asdf'>display div</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name = 'submit' value='Apply'>
<div style='display:none;' id='rrrr'>display this section</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`String.prototype.indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), in this way: `this.value.indexOf('ABCD') > -1`.

> The **`indexOf()`** method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at `fromIndex`. Returns **`-1`** if the value is not found.

Something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').on('change', function() {

      if (this.value.indexOf('ABCD') > -1) {
        $("#rrrr").show();
      } else {
        $("#rrrr").hide();
      }


    });
  })
</script>

<select id='test' name='test'>
  <option value='123'>hide div</option>
  <option value='ABCD,asdf'>display div</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Apply'>

<div style='display:none;' id='rrrr'>

  display this section
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `slice()` and `indexOf()` will help you out here. `slice(a, b)` will return a section of the string from a to b and `indexOf()` will return the place in the string where the character is first found which is what we'll use for the second value in slice.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value.slice(0, this.value.indexOf(",")) === 'ABCD')
  {
    $("#rrrr").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#rrrr").hide();
  }


   });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test' name = 'test'>
    <option value = '123'>hide div</option>
    <option value = 'ABCD,asdf'>display div</option>
      </select>
      <input type='submit' name = 'submit' value='Apply'>

     <div style='display:none;' id='rrrr'>

     display this section
           </div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, all your suggestions worked. @afrotonder - I need 2 values becuase I am working on a hardware project where I need to display the DIV based on the hardware's chipset and when I submit the form, I need to get the device's MAC address. There is no way to get the unique MAC from just the chipset which is why I need 2 values

Comment: I am not sure how to select all your suggestions as the good one since they all worked

Comment: @Gino Stack only allows for one accepted answer so it can sort it to the top for people who come across the post later while looking for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird what you want to do, as I have no clue why you would need two values in one. Anyways, I believe what youre looking for has been answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245995/11296950

The solution shown is storing an object as a value and setting the object value to an array with your values.

Hope it helps!