# How to pass two id values from one drop down with PHP

Tags: php, post, foreach, drop-down-menu

I have one dropdown with a foreach loop which will pass to model using post method.

```
   <div class="form-group" ">
       <select class="form-control" id="rel" name="rl[][rel]" >
          <option></option>
          <?php
            foreach ($relationship as $row) {
                                            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->relID; ?>"><?php echo $row->relCat; ?></option>
                 <?php
                     }
                       ?>
                   </select>
              </div>
```

and in the model it is getting the proper values using post method. As

```
$rel = $_POST['rel'];
```

Here the problem is when the user select one option ,I want to get two values like

```
 "<?php echo $row->relID; ?>" and "<?php echo $row->relCatID; ?>"
```

like

```
$rel = $_POST['rel']; //this for the $row ->relID
$relcat = $_POST['relcat'];//this for the $row ->relCatID
```

I want to get both from one selection without adding any visble dropdown or element..

Comment: Cant you just use an associative array to store $rows and then use the id to get the according category like: `$rows[$relId}->relCatID`. Otherwise just seperate the values by comma and pass them as one string and explode it in php: `list($relId, $relCat) = explode(",", $_POST["rel"]);`

Comment: Just querying the `relcat` based on `relId`, like @CodeSpirit says, seems best. Otherwise how are you planning to handle a case where someone alters the request so that the `rel` and `relCat` do not mach with `$row->relID` and `$row->relCatID`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an Option in a Select tag carry multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code with ajax call

In Javascript code get value

```
var name = $('#rel option:selected').attr('data-cat_id');
var id = $('#rel').val();
```

```
<div class="form-group" >
  <select class="form-control" id="rel" name="rl[][rel]" >
    <option></option>
    <?php foreach ($relationship as $row) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row->relID; ?>" data-cat_id="<?php echo $row->relCatID; ?>"><?php echo $row->relCat; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `('data-cat_id);` is missing a closing `'`

Comment: `<?php echo $row->relCatID;` is missing the closing `?>`

Comment: yes i found that

Comment: `<div class="form-group" ">` has an unneeded `"`