# How can I save multiple select box data to database like json format in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a multiple select box.

[Multiple select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClGgM.png)

This is my blade.

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="service_id">Services *</label>
                                    <select class="select2" multiple="multiple" name="service_id[]" required
                                        data-placeholder="Select Services" style="width: 100%;">
                                        @foreach($services as $service)
                                        <option value="{{$service->services_id}}">{{$service->services_name}}
                                        </option>

                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

As you can see i only send {{$service->services_id}} for value i want to send {{$service->services_price}} as well and save to the database like JSON format.

It should be save to the table like this '{"1":"5000", "2":3000, "2":6666}' in database.

How can i do that ?

I dont think it will help you but this is my Controller

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    //
    // Form validation (Zorunlu Alanlar)
    $this->validate(request(), [
        
        'customer_id' => 'required',
        'service_id' => 'required',
        'offer_score' => 'required',
        'tag_id' => 'required',
    



 


       
    ]);     



    $offers = new Offers;
    $offers->service_id           = implode(',', $req->service_id);
    $offers->offer_status         = $req->offer_status;
    $offers->customer_id          = $req->customer_id;
    $offers->offer_score          = $req->offer_score;
    $offers->tag_id               = $req->tag_id;
    $offers->offer_discount       = $req->offer_discount;
    $offers->offer_reminder_date  = $req->offer_reminder_date;
    $offers->user_company_id      = $req->user_company_id;
    $offers->user_id              = $req->user_id;
    $customers2 = Customers::all();

  

         $offers->updateTimestamps();
        $offers->save();





    return redirect()->back()->with('success', true);
}
```

Comment: try this json_encode($req->service_id)

Comment: But i want to get service_price as well

Comment: it should be like this {"1":"5000", "2":3000, "2":6666}  id - price

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an Option in a Select tag carry multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values)

Comment: This is for select box, only for one value. I want to select multiple.

Comment: You can join the service_id and service_price with a char, for instance "|" or something else. And then you send "1|5000" as the option's value. In your Controller, split the service_id and service_price into an array, then jsonencode it

Comment: Yes i thinked that before but there are multiple values, that is the part i am having trouble.

Comment: What is your `$services ` code like? You can join the id and price in `$services` or join in the HTML template. In my opinion, it's better to join it in `$services`.

Comment: <option value="{{$service->services_id}}|{{$service->services_price}};"> i did like this and this is the output "32|1500;|33|2000;|34|3000;|35|3500;"

Comment: i guess i should use foreach loop or something to get every id and price in a array.

Comment: I see, convert the string  "32|1500;|33|2000;|34|3000;|35|3500;" to {"1":"5000", "2":3000, "2":6666} will solve your issue,  is it correct?

Comment: yes definitely, i am trying to do this right now.

Comment: Why there is a "|" at the beginning of the second pair?

Comment: i dont have any idea

Comment: i changed something and somehow output is like this now ["33|2000","34|3000","35|3500"] maybe its helpful for you.

Comment: The problem-solving idea is similar, you almost get there. Check out the answer I just post, I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You may also echo the results of any PHP function. In fact, you can put any PHP code you wish inside of a Blade echo statement](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade)

1. Join the id and price in the template

   ```
   <option value="{{join('|', [$service->services_id, $service->services_price])}}">{{$service->services_name}}
   ```

   so, the value you send to the server may look like this "32|1500;33|2000;34|3000;35|3500;"
2. Split the string in your controller

   ```
   $sample = "32|1500;33|2000;34|3000;35|3500;";

   $pair = array_filter(explode(";", trim($string, ";")), function($s){return strlen($s) > 0;});
   $idPrice = [];
   foreach($pair as $row) {
       list($key, $value) = explode("|", $row);
       $idPrice[$key] = $value;
   }

   //var_dump(json_encode($idPrice));
   //string(49) "{"32":"1500","33":"2000","34":"3000","35":"3500"}"
   ```